# How to open popup at right corner?

Tags: asp.net

I am opening a popup window from javascript using window.open. I want to open this popup window at right corner of the page (height="700px" width="400px"). How can i achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the following method as:

```
popUpAtMyWish("yourpage","windownamehere",500,600);



function popUpAtMyWish( pageToLoad, winName, width, height)
{
    xposition=0; yposition=0;
    if ((parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4 )){
        xposition = (screen.width - width);
        yposition = (screen.height - height);
    }

    var args = "";
        args += "width=" + width + "," + "height=" + height + ","
        + "location=0,"
        + "menubar=0,"
        + "resizable=0,"
        + "scrollbars=0,"
        + "statusbar=false,dependent,alwaysraised,"
        + "status=false,"
        + "titlebar=no,"
        + "toolbar=0,"
        + "hotkeys=0,"
        + "screenx=" + xposition + ","  //NN Only
        + "screeny=" + yposition + ","  //NN Only
        + "left=" + xposition + ","     //IE Only
        + "top=" + yposition;           //IE Only
        var dmcaWin = window.open(pageToLoad,winName,args );
        dmcaWin.focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks,I just wanted to get screen working area in javascript. When i set window.open(...height=0) it opens the popup at topmost position of the web browser.